Floor jack size for Silverado 1500
2010 Silverado 1500 extended cab; 5,000 lbs
What size of floor jack is suitable for jacking up a single front  wheel off of
the ground? (onto a jack stand)
I'm used to working with lighter cars, not trucks.

I don't know what the smallest size would be for a floor jack, but anything over a 1-ton rating would be more than capable of lifting one corner of a truck without issue. The bigger issue with a Silverado is to ensure you have enough travel in your floor jack to successfully lift it. Anything with that sort of travel is probably going to be 3-ton or better lifting capacity, which would be enough (theoretically) to lift the entire vehicle.

Thanks. I purchased a 3.5 ton floor jack. It worked well; it had enough travel to lift a front wheel off the ground when jacked on the frame. https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/big-red-heavy-duty-garage-floor-jack-w-quick-start-3-5-ton-0090261p.html?rq=floor+jack
